# How to find TOP N compoent in my sql

Tags: mysql

I have table like this

```
id  status  component
-------------------------
001  A      Component7
002  C      Component7
003  B      Component1
004  A      Component1
005  A      Component2
006  B      Component5
007  A      Component3
```

I want top 3 component

```
Top-component    
------------
Component7
component1
component2
```

can anybody help me out? thanks in advance

Comment: What criteria determines the ranking of "TOP" - e.g. count, status, etc?

Comment: You question is not very clear to me. Can you explain how you generated that top 3 component

Comment: are you want to order by your `status`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want top 3 distinct components as I guess so then try query defined below:

```
Select distinct component from `your-tablename` order by id ASC limit 3
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table`
GROUP BY `component`
ORDER BY `id`
LIMIT 3
```